# Update UI in real time with angular and express

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, express

I have two UIs, one for `order.html` and one for `ledger.html` running on two different ports 3000 and 8000 on `localhost` . On the `order` page, a user can place an order for an item. Once he places the order, the information is sent as a `POST` request to server on port 8000.

Below is the post request from the `order.html` page to server with port 8000

```
  $scope.sendPostRequest=function(){
    var dataToBeSent = $scope.postData;
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/receiveOrder',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      data: 'some random data'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        //extracts key:value pairs from the json sent back
        $scope.postResponse= someResponse

      }, function errorCallback(error) {
        // some error handler functions here

      })
  }
```

Below is the express code at port 8000 to receive the above request.

```
app.post('/receiveOrder', function(req, res){
    console.log('type of request '+Type(req));
    //extract the text passed in data section of the post request
    //TODO: Use the data received to update the dashboard, ledger.html
    //send some response back as confirmation
});
```

Once the `POST` request is received and the data sent is parsed using `body-parser`, I need to update the UI of `ledger.html` page to show this.

Basically, `ledger.html` keeps track of the orders placed by users in real time. It is a dashboard in which fresh orders keep getting added as they are placed. I am stuck in achieving the above.

I have experimented with using `socket.io` by way of using `event-emitters` but could not go very far. I have a schema setup for the order data in MongoDB as well in case I need it.

May I have some guidance about what I can use to achieve the above.

Comment: what is `Type()` ?

Comment: it confirms the Type of the request sent, post/ put/ get/ delete. Basically i have just put it to check in case some requests were sent to that url which were not POST requests.